# React - Child onClick event doesn't trigger when binding parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is the following.

- I have a "BookShelf" component which contains a "Book" list.
- The parent (bookshelf) manage in its state a "selectedBook" property.
- When clicking on one child (book), *I would like* to update its parent *selectedBook* property.
- To achieve this, I use a function defined in the parent properties.
- **But this method is never trigerred** (I tried with a console.log('something') but it never shows.

See my code below :

```
setSelectedBook(index) {
    this.setState({
        selectedBook: index
    })
},
getInitialState() {
    return {
        books: [],
        selectedBook: null
    }
},
componentDidMount() {
    let component = this
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data/books.json',
        success (data) {
            component.setState({
                books: data
            })
        },
        error (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
},
render() {
    let component = this
    var bookList = this.state.books.map(function(book, index) {
        let selectBook = component.setSelectedBook.bind(component, index)
        return (
             <Book onClick={selectBook} data={book} key={index} />
         )
    })
    return <div className="book-shelf">
        {bookList}
    </div>
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How your `Book` component triggers `onClick`? You need to trigger `props.onClick()` explicitly in `Book` component

Comment: Could you please paste the code for the `Book` component?

Comment: I may have missed something. The onClick isn't triggered only by adding it in the book declararation ?

Comment: @OhmWang `onClick` is just property on your custom component, react doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example for you. Also [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/889/)

You should pass your `onClick` event as a props to child component, once child component gets it, it will call a callback and pass an id as an agrument to the callback (like i have below).

```
class Book extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick(){
    this.props.click(this.props.id)
  }
    render(){
    return  <li onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.id} - {this.props.name}</li>
  }
}

class BookShelf extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)
  }
  onClick(id){
    console.log(id)
  }
  render(){
    return <ul> // of course you may use Array.map functions, it's just for example
      <Book click={this.onClick} id={1} name={'hello'}/>
      <Book click={this.onClick} id={2} name={'world'}/>
    </ul>
  }
}

React.render(<BookShelf />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Also i suggest look at this [article](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) *Communicate Between Components*, it will be useful for you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

select method return anonymous function as value.

```
<Book onClick={this.selectBook(index)} data={book} key={index} />
```

```js
 selectBook (index){
       return ((() => {
            console.log(" selectBook fired" );
            component.setState({selectedBook:index}); 
              }).bind(component,index))
      
  }
```